# Palette API returning negative values?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

So I have to use the palette API in this app I am building to dynamically change the status bar color and when I pass the value I get to the method to change the status bar color of the app crashes with a **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color**

I am formatting it correctly regardless by adding the requires "#" in front of the number and also passing it as a String but the app still crashes.

This is the code snippet I used to do it.

```
        binding.viewpagerMain.registerOnPageChangeCallback(
            object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback(){
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    var headerImage : Int? = null

                    when(position){
                        0 -> headerImage = R.drawable.character
                        1 -> headerImage = R.drawable.planets
                        2 -> headerImage = R.drawable.films
                        3 -> headerImage = R.drawable.species
                        4 -> headerImage = R.drawable.vehicles
                        5 -> headerImage = R.drawable.starships
                    }

                    if (headerImage != null) {
                        imageview_main.setImageResource(headerImage)
                        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, headerImage)
                        Palette.from(bitmap).generate {

                            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                            val paletteColor: Int? = it?.getDarkVibrantColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                            Log.e("MainFragment", "#${paletteColor}")
                            (activity as MainActivity).updateStatusBarColor("#${paletteColor.toString()}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

This is the activity function that I run

```
    open fun updateStatusBarColor(color: String?) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val window: Window = window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            window.statusBarColor = Color.parseColor(color)
        }
    }
```

Added a log call to know what the output was, and I got values like which were negative

```
#2131034159
#-14678008
#-15191992
#-7325688
```

I don't why the values are negative or if they can be, I assumed they where hex values and passed them , but they still don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Color are stored as 32-bit integers on Android, as explained in the [Color ints](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#color-ints) documentation. If the most significant bit is 1, the value is interpreted negative because the integer is signed. However interpreting it as signed makes no sense in the context of colors. In fact, all values that can be taken by an integer are valid colors.

Here's two solutions for fixing your logging statment:

- `"#${(paletteColor.toLong() and 0xFFFFFFFF).toString(16)}"`. Increase the bit width of your color and apply 32-bit mask so the most significant bit is 0 and value appears as positive.
- `"#${paletteColor.toUInt().toString(16)}"`. Use an unsigned integer. (requires having experimental unsigned numbers compiler option in Kotlin)

I prefer the first one.

For actually changing the color, I don't know if you realized what you're here: you're getting a color int, converting it to a string, then parsing it back to the original int! Why add an unnecessary step? Just use the int returned from `getDarkVibrantColor` to update `window.statusBarColor`.

Comment: Thank you! The first solution still returned some negative values but the second one worked! Will remove the unnecessary conversions!